# Count the duration between 2 time in scala ( streaming)

Tags: scala, streaming

I have a list of events and I need to count the time duration between the 2 events. The previous event can be in another window. How to do it? I use scala and streaming(mini-batches). I wrote the next but I had a mistake :"Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;"

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

 val ttt = tester
  .withWatermark("time", "1 minutes")
  .groupBy(
   window($"time", "1 minutes", "10 seconds"),
   $"nodeId"
      )
.count()
.withColumn("WindowSize",(col("window.end").cast("Long") - 
col("window.start").cast("Long")) / 60)
.withColumn("prev_time" ,lead(col("window.start"), 1)
.over(Window.partitionBy("nodeId").orderBy("window.start")))
```

Comment: Are you using any specific streaming framework: Spark, Akka, Flink, Monix???... A Scala 2.13 LazyList?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I use Microsoft AzureDatabricks and Scala 2.13

Comment: I suppose that it is Spark. You can use Spark Windows to do that. Take a look to https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez can you look at my code?